# Read text document within visual studio project

Tags: c#, .net

I've added a .txt file with a bunch of text to my project,
now I need to read that file and print it in a richtextbox.

Any clue how to access the file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should put it in your resources, accessible under My Project > Resources. Choose "Add Existing File" and import your text file. Then, you'll be able to access it *as a string* using the syntax `Properties.Resources.<resource name>`, which you can assign to your RichTextBox's `Text` property.

Alternatively, to read from a file, you can use [`System.IO.File.ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx) if you need the entire contents as a string.

Comment: Alright thanks, I havn't worked with that before so thanks ^^

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to embed the file as resource, you can set `Copy to Output Directory` to `true`. Then you can use `File.ReadAllLines(filename)` to read all lines from the file as `string[]`. Then you can set the text with `textBox.Text`.

If you want to embed it, see the other post by @minitech.

Comment: that just tries to load up the debug/text.txt

Comment: If the file is copied to the output directory, you simply load the text with `File.ReadAllLines("text.txt")`.